# Webpack and JS source maps. How does this ever work?

Tags: webpack

Medium sized project. Have the following option in webpack.config.js:

**1.**
`devtool: 'source-maps'`

When `debugger` is set, the browser pretty much crashes.

ok...

**2.**
setting it to:
`eval: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map'`
code is not source mapped...
i.e. async functions are wrapped in `regeneratorRuntime.wrap ...`

**3.**

ok lets try `eval-cheap-module-source-map`

`devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map'`
This does source map it correctly. But half the time the `step over` function is enabled.
My computer is crawling to a halt. What is up with this?

---

**Using Firefox**

`devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map'`

The first breakpoint looks ok. 
Things are source mapped. But then it 'jumps' into another context, and boom... many `regeneratorRuntime.wrap ...` everywhere. It's no longer source mapped.

---

How are people actually using Webpack and source maps with any success? This just seems totally unusable.

---

Comment: `devtool: 'source-map'` with property `sourceMap: true` in css/sass loaders works for me. Example of my [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/cichy380/html-starter-bs4-webpack/blob/300ca6de0b9f712012101f0cb131282b7eabebae/webpack.config.js)

Comment: I should mention it is for Javascript

Comment: same problem, maybe relate to regeneratorRuntime